# expand firstLevel Tree in angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I created a tree in Angular. That tree has 3 levels. When the tree is loaded, the first level is opened. 
[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tree-mateiral-multilevel)

I want the do something like add or delete in this tree and I need when I do action in this tree it opens the level 1.

I am using this code but it's not working for me :

```
     @ViewChild('tree') tree;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tree.treeControl.expandAll();
  }
```

how can I solve how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open specific node of the tree, you could flatten the tree using [`FlatTreeControl`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/tree/api#FlatTreeControl) and use it's [`expand()`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/tree/control/base-tree-control.ts#L45) method. One thing to note is to open an sub-node, all it's parent nodes need to be opened as well. Try the following

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<TreeNode>(
      node => node.level, node => node.expandable);
  .
  .
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.treeControl.expand(this.treeControl.dataNodes[0]);   // <-- open root node
    this.treeControl.expand(this.treeControl.dataNodes[1]);   // <-- open node 1
  }
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tree-mateiral-multilevel-mgjhmt).

Comment: i just open level 1 not all of them

Comment: @mrcoder: It works in the Stackblitz. So there is clearly something missing or obstructing it in your main project. To solve that you have to show the code from your main project. Make sure you have all the dependencies installed and imported. Do you get any error or it just doesn't work?